# How to Use ZSSRichTextEditor in UITextView or UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitextview

I'm using `RichTextEditor` in Project to Edit HTML coming from server but any `RTeditor` removes links and images available in HTML , now I found a `ZSSRichTexteditor` but no easy way to use in existing project , will somebody help me how I use this using a `TextFile` or `UIWebview` , will be great help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I created ZSSRichTextEditor, and it should be simple to add to your project. What issues are you having?

Comment: i added to project and header files but still now able to use it , don't know how to alloc it with UIWEBVIEW frame

Comment: Please look at the example project and the github page. It should be all you need.

Comment: already tried but it says make it subclass i did still not workable , do i need to use another class with Xib for this editor

Comment: What exactly is not working? All you have to do is use a UIViewController and subclass it. Include the required files as instructed on github. Let me know what errors you get.

Comment: i was looking for method to use it in existing one instead creating a new UIViewContoller/xib file

Comment: You cannot embed it, if that is what you were looking for.